# Simplifying a Binomial Series

Tags: combinatorics

- Suppose you have two people : PersonA and PersonB
- There is a pile of $n = p+q$ marbles.
- PersonA takes marbles and PersonB marbles in random order until there are no marbles left.

**I am interested in knowing how many ways can marbles be selected such that PersonA is always has more marbles than PersonB at every point.**

Here is the logic I am using:

- Case 1: If PersonB takes the first marble, all ways after are invalid.

In this situation, the number of invalid ways become:

$$
C(n, r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
$$

$$C( P+Q -1 , Q-1) = \frac{(P+Q-1)!}{(Q-1)!(P+Q-1-(Q-1))!}$$

- Case2: If PersonA takes the first marble and PersonB takes 2 marbles in a row, then all ways after are discarded. I think this will become:

$$C(P+Q-2, Q-2) = \frac{(P+Q-2)!}{(Q-2)!(P+Q-2-(Q-2))!}$$

I tried to pick up on a generic pattern:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{q} C(n - k, q - k) = C(n, q) + C(n - 1, q - 1) + C(n - 2, q - 2) + \ldots + C(n - q, 0) = \frac{n!}{q!(n-q)!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{(q-1)!(n-q)!} + \frac{(n-2)!}{(q-2)!(n-q)!} + \ldots + \frac{(n-q)!}{0!(n-q)!}
$$

**My Question:** Based on this formulation, can we show that this sum will always simplify to: $$\sum_{k=0}^{q} C(n - k, q - k) = \frac{p-q}{p+q}$$

Thanks!

- References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: The way this is worded, person A has to take at least two marbles before person B can take any, is that the intent?

Comment: That is probability not number of ways that sum cannot converge to a fraction all its terms are integers

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^q {n-k\choose q-k}&={n\choose q}+{n-1\choose q-1}...+{n-q+1\choose q+1}+{n-q\choose 0}\\&={n\choose q}+{n-1\choose q-1}...+{n-q+1\choose 1}+{n-q+1\choose 0}\\&={n\choose q}+{n-1\choose q-1}...+{n-q+2\choose 1}
\\&={n+1\choose q}
\end{align}
$$

The result you have is the probability

$$
P=\frac{{n+1 \choose q}}{n \choose p}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(p+1)!q!}\frac{p!q!}{n!}=\frac{n+1}{p+1}>1
$$

So the series you found is probably wrong

Comment: @ RandomGuy: Thank you so much for your answer! I see your current score is 666 :)

Comment: totally not an anagram of santa i assure you